# How to create your own App Service Site Extension in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-deployment

Please forward me some links/how-to guides for developing your own App service site extension for Azure. I am trying to intercept HTTP traffic going to/coming out from my App service and do some pre-checks / alter a few things as a part of the extension.

I didn't find any documents on developing your custom extension for Microsoft Azure App Service.

Can this extension be implemented in Golang? If yes, please share examples too.

Comment: What is the framework and version of your App?

Comment: So,you want to create an extension from your code ?

Comment: @Brijesh Vajera You need to create your custom site extension by creating your own nuget package and then add it in - SCM_SITEEXTENSIONS_FEED_URL App Setting to https://www.siteextensions.net/api/v2/ where - https://www.siteextensions.net/api/v2/is your nuget url Refer here- https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/87. Once that is added, You can install existing extension as well as your created extensions from here- https://i.imgur.com/f2jR9Yu.png

Comment: One last question: Can this extension be created in Golang? If so, can somebody gives me example?

Comment: AFAIK, Only Nuget based packages are allowed in Azure Site extensions and Golang based is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add the custom extension that intercepts the Http Requests in your application, You need to create one custom Nuget package built with your extension and publish it as a package in **`nuget.org.`**

*I created one `Asp.NET` MVC application:-*

**Added one class that intercepts traffic:-**

**`TrafficInterceptorMiddleware.cs:-`**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TrafficInterceptorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TrafficInterceptorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Perform pre-checks or modifications here before the request is processed

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"))
        {
            // Perform pre-checks for requests to /admin endpoint
            // For instance, you can perform authentication, logging, etc.
            // Example: 
            // Check if the user is authenticated
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized Access");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Before handling the request further, you can put your logic here.

        await _next(context);

        // Perform actions after the response has been generated (if needed)
        // For example:
        // Log response details, modify response headers, etc.
    }
}
```

Called this package in my **`Program.cs:-`**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Add middleware to the pipeline
app.UseMiddleware<TrafficInterceptorMiddleware>();

// Configure routes and endpoints
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Now, I built this project and added the **.dll path** in the **.nuspec file.**

Create one **`.nuspec file`** with the contents below:-

**`Traffic.nuspec`**

In order for your package to be added in Azure Site Extension add this line of code in your **`.nuspec`**:-

```
<tags>AzureSiteExtension</tags>
        <packageTypes>
            <packageType name="AzureSiteExtension" />
        </packageTypes>
```

**Complete code:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>YourMiddlewarePackageId</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>TrafficInterceptorMiddleware</title>
        <authors>Siddhesh</authors>
        <owners>Siddhesh</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Middleware for intercepting HTTP traffic in ASP.NET 6.0 applications.</description>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" version="6.0.0" />
        </dependencies>
        <releaseNotes>Release notes for version 1.0.0.</releaseNotes>
        <tags>AzureSiteExtension</tags>
        <packageTypes>
            <packageType name="AzureSiteExtension" />
        </packageTypes>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Debug\net6.0\WebApplication40.dll" target="lib\net6.0" />
        <file src="README.md" target="" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Now, Add run the command below in your nuget CLI:-

You can add **`nuget.exe`** in your current project and run the command from the Visual Studio Command Line tool too:-

```
nuget pack Traffic.nuspec
```

**Output:-**

[image]

I directly uploaded the package by logging into my Nuget account by referring this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package):-

[image]

***After uploading your package will get validated > published > indexed > publicly available:-***

[image]

After your package is published, Visit your Azure extensions page and the Package is visible for installation:-

[image]

***In Advanced Tools Kudu > Site Extensions>***

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Site Extensions are moving to nuget.org by August 2018 · Issue #87 · Azure/app-service-announcements (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/87)